# Create Page Path Table in BigQuery (Path Analysis ; Unpivot )

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to recreate a table for path analysis in BigQuery (similar to unpivot). 
For each person, I have his/her page path data like follows.

```
[visitor]   [page]     [page_orders]  
A,  Pa, 1
A,  Pb, 2
A,  Pc, 3
A,  Pb, 4
A,  Pf, 5
B,  Px, 1
B,  Pb, 2
B,  Pz, 3
B,  Pk, 4
C,  Pb, 1
C,  Pz, 2
C,  Pa, 3
```

And I would like to create tables like this.

```
[visitor]       [page_path]
A,  Pz > Pb > Pc > Pa > Pf
B,  Px > Pb > Pz > Pk 
C,  Pb > Pz > Pa
```

What I have done is to create a table like this:

```
[visitor] [Pa] [Pb] [Pc] [Pf] [Pk] [Px] [Pz]
A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
A, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
A, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
A, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
A, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
B, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 
C, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
C, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
C, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

AND then I can get a table like this

```
A, Pa Pb Pc Pf Pz
B, Pb Pk Px Pz
C, Pa Pb Pz
```

However, the page orders is not correct.

Is there any better idea to create correct page path table via BigQuery?
(It seemed I cannot create variables nor using loop in BigQuery...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT visitor, GROUP_CONCAT(page, ' > ') as page_path
FROM (
  SELECT visitor, page, page_order 
  FROM YourTable
  ORDER BY visitor, page_order
)
GROUP BY visitor
```

Another option: with use of [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) (has no dependency on order by that Mosha pointed in his comment - but UDF have their own limitations - so you will need to choose)

```
SELECT visitor, page_path FROM JS(
// input table
(
  SELECT visitor, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(STRING(100000 + page_order), ',', page), ';') AS list
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY visitor
) ,
// input columns
visitor, list,
// output schema
"[
{name: 'visitor', type: 'string'},
{name: 'page_path', type: 'string'}
]",
// function
"function(r, emit){
  var list = r.list.split(';');
  list.sort();
  path = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) path += ' > ';
    path += list[i].split(',')[1];
  }
    emit({
      visitor: r.visitor,
      page_path: path
    });
 }"
)
```

Comment: Please note that inner ORDER BY does not guarantee the order of pages in GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: that's true - at the same time practice shows that it works almost 100% (if not exactly) with GROUP_CONCAT. but sure - to be used at owner risk :o)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail!! You have offered very useful information and have solved my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . My issue with `GROUP_CONCAT()` in BigQuery is that it doesn't *guarantee* the ordering of the path.  That is important for this problem.  Do you have a reference that there is an ordering that is guaranteed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Agree it doesn't and I don't have. Check second option in my answer. If `order` is a must for the question's example - UDF option can be used. Order here is guaranteed. Even more - if user is willing to use Standard SQL version that is in early alpha  - check Mosha's answer. There is always a choice between this and that depend on given circumstances

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery support for standard SQL, this can be solved by using native operations on ARRAYs.
Below is one possible solution:

```
select visitor, (select string_agg(p, ' --> ') from t.pages p) from
(select visitor, array(select p.page from t.pages p order by p.page_order asc) pages from
(select visitor, array_agg(struct(page, page_order)) pages
 from VisitsTable group by visitor) t) t
```

For clearness the solution is written as 3 subselects (it is possible to write it in shorter form, but it won't change performance). Explanations:

1. Innermost ARRAY_AGG aggregation builds for every visitor an ARRAY of STRUCTs. Each STRUCT has STRING page and INT64 page_order.
2. Second subselect runs ORDER BY **within** each array. It sorts pages by their order.
3. Outermost subselect simply computes STRING_AGG of all strings in each ARRAY, using ' --> ' as separator.

For more details, see documentation at: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation on your original data:

```
select visitor,
       concat(max(case when page_order = 1 then page else '' end), 
              max(case when page_order = 2 then concat(' --> ', page) else '' end),
              max(case when page_order = 3 then concat(' --> ', page)  else '' end), 
              max(case when page_order = 4 then concat(' --> ', page)  else '' end), 
              max(case when page_order = 5 then concat(' --> ', page)  else '' end),
              max(case when page_order = 6 then concat(' --> ', page)  else '' end),
              max(case when page_order = 7 then concat(' --> ', page)  else '' end)
 ) as path
             )
from t
group by visitor;
```